# Unable to start chrome driver - macOS - selenium java - testing

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver

when I'm trying to do maven install, process is getting stopped by this error 
any help would be so great. stuck since 2 days.

java code which is failing at

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.setBinary(System.getProperty("binary_path"));
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().build();
driver = new ChromeDriver(service, opt); <-- at this line.
```

Error out of console

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 28707
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1585902743.548][WARNING]: FromSockAddr failed on netmask
[ERROR] Tests run: 11, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 10, Time elapsed: 1.386 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] setUpScript(com.***.TestBase)  Time elapsed: 1.149 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

PS: its an electron application & running in macOS

Comment: refer this https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this argument:

```
opt.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

It's because this message **DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist**

Comment: didnt work! PS: its an electron application, im trying to test it in macOS.

Comment: Add above argument